# How can it be ignoring my style in the div it is assigned?

Tags: html, css, blazor-server-side

This is all part of a Blazor app using DevExpress and so creating a MRE is impossible as there are 108 included CSS & JS files. With that said, the issue is very straightforward.

The underlying HTML of interest is:

```
<div class="my-main-scrollbar">
```

the underlying CSS of interest is:

```
.my-main-scrollbar {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

When I open F12 and select the above `<div>` and then look at combined - there is no value set for overflow or height. They are not being applied.

The generated HTML (view page source) is:

```
<div class="my-main-scrollbar" b-jv8gxb7csr>
```

And the generated css is:

```
.my-main-scrollbar[b-jv8gxb7csr] {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

This is due to Blazor creating the css on the fly from the file MyPage.razor.css.

Any idea why in this case these CSS settings are not being applied?

**Update:**

I'm seeing some other css not getting applied form the auto-generated css file. So I think something is wrong in what Blazor is doing. But the auto-generated files does exist, is correctly linked to, and has the expected content.

Comment: it should work correctly, do you have check that your css file is loaded correctly?

Comment: @Frankusky I clicked on the css link in the page source and that brought it up. So yes, it's finding it. But I'm looking elsewhere and there's other places where the css is clearly not getting applied. I rebooted to be double careful - and still have the problem.

Comment: Is at least anything from the CSS file applied?

Comment: @Ferris as best as I can tell - no. Yet the css file is there. Could the `b-jv8gxb7csr` be the problem?

Comment: Did you import the resources as specified in the msft docs? _content/assemblyname/ etc etc. ?

Comment: The `b-jv8gxb7csr` is the unique code generated to identify the css specific to the component.  The compiler sometimes gets confused about which identity is currently in play.  I find a clean and full rebuild of the solution solves the problem.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Ding! We have a winner! I restarted Visual Studio, did a rebuild all, and now it's all there. thank you. Please put that as an answer so I can accept it and others can find this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `b-jv8gxb7csr` is part of coding for component CSS isolation: it's the unique code generated by the build process and inserted into the generated Css and component code to identify the Css specific to the component.

The compiler sometimes gets confused about which identity is currently in play. A clean and full rebuild of the solution normally solves the problem.